# Django View without a rendered Response

Tags: python, django, response

I want to use a Button to pass an Integer through the URL to my views.py.
I want this function in the views.py not to load any new templates or show HttpResponses.

Is there a way to call this function by the push of a button, but not reload a new page?

Here is the Button in the HTML Template:

```
<a button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" href="../../frage1f1/1/">1</a>
```

Here is the urls.py Part:

```
path('frage1f1/<int:f1>/', views.frage1f1),
```

Here is the Python Method in the views.py:

```
def frage1f1(request, f1):
collection = database["Survey_1"]
collection.update_one({"_id": ObjectId(document_id)}, {"$set":{Frage1: f1}}, upsert= True)
return HttpResponse("Frage 1 beantwortet")
```

I just want to pass the integer to the fuction and not reload a new page.
Is this possible?

I am very new to this and would be very thankful for any advice.

Thanks in advance.
Greetings

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one solution is to use AJAX, then a request is sent to the server but the page is not reloaded. [Tutorial using jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

example using jQuery (You have include the [jQuery library](https://code.jquery.com/) for it to work):

Inside template

```
<a button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" href="#">1</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', 'a.btn', function(){

        //get the number inside button
        number = $(this).html();

        //send ajax request to the server
        $.ajax({
           url: "../../frage1f1/" + number + "/", 
           success: function(result){}
       });

    });
</script>
```